# Entity Framework source codes does not compile successfully with .NET Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I want reference to `EF` source codes projects instead its assemblies in my project for some tracing goals, so I downloaded `EF` source codes from [CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), and add it to my project, it compiles well by `.NET Framework 4.5`, but my project is in `.NET Framework 4`(I have to stay with `.NET4`), when I change its target framework to `.NET 4` it could not compile successfully, I get some errors, e.g:

> Error  29  The type or namespace name 'DatabaseGeneratedOption' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\8060509\Downloads\entityframework-899f1fb43a0d92c22ea381edafc50a350e391a5a\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Configuration\Properties\Primitive\Api\BinaryPropertyConfiguration.cs    102 13  EntityFramework

and

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'ColumnAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\8060509\Downloads\entityframework-899f1fb43a0d92c22ea381edafc50a350e391a5a\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Conventions\Configuration\Property\ColumnAttributeConvention.cs  13  61  EntityFramework

and
...

What is the solution?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the version of the source you downloaded supports .net 4? In other words, is there any reason to believe that what you are attempting is actually possible?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The official NuGet package does support .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the target framework of the "Debug" or "Release" configurations. Entity Framework is already set up with usable "DebugNet40" and "ReleaseNet40" configurations that you should be using instead. Those configurations, in addition to setting the target framework, also define the required macros that EF uses to know which code to include in the .NET 4.0 version.

Comment: Where and how can I config `EF` to use `DebugNet40` or `ReleaseNet40`?

Comment: From the configuration drop down if you are building in VS, or by specifying the config on the command line if builing with msbuild

Answer (score 0):

I think `DatabaseGeneratedOption` doesn't exist in EF before 4.5. Change your target framework to 4.5 and it should do well.

Comment: As I said in my question, I have to work with `.NET4`.